# Want to use variable in RC reference with If

Tags: excel, vba, navbar

i want to use RC reference to check if value is greater than Threshold(Variable) then it should result in RC[-2] else RC[-1] however i am not able to provide variable in below formula.Can anyone please help

```
Threshold=3000
Cells(12,13)="=If(RC[-1]=0,if(RC[-2]>="&Threshold&",RC[-2],RC[-1]),RC[-1])"
```

Comment: `Cells(12,13).FormulaR1C1 =...` If you are trying to return a formula to that cell you need that property.

Comment: put blanks before and after both `&`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. It is working fine now